# Yii folder structure and global configuration for n applications

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, boilerplate

I'm building a folder structure and global configuration to allow me to create applications on Yii framework where all applications could share common codes, extensions or modules.

The idea is, each application would have the business level for that application, but, everything that can be shared between applications, we want to use as a common repository (models, extensions, widgets, etc)

For example, we want to share the [Auth](https://github.com/Crisu83/yii-auth) extension to control the system permission, but I want to 'install' Auth under the common folder instead under each application.

Below, the architecture that I would like to build:

[image: Architecture of the applications]

I found the [YiiBoilerplate](https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBoilerplate) as something similar, but they don'y configure Yii in such way that we want to.

The folder structure desire is:

```
common/
    css/
    images/
    protected/
        commands/ 
        components/ 
        config/ 
        controllers/ 
        extensions/ 
        models/ 
        views/ 
Application1/
    css/
    images/
    protected/
        commands/ 
        components/ 
        config/ 
        controllers/ 
        extensions/ 
        models/ 
        views/
```

So, let's go for some points:

1. If my user is under the application X (www.applicationx.com) and the login page is a 'common' structure I want to display to user something like this: www.applicationx.com/index.php?r=user/login.
2. I want to be able to 'navigate' between the application folder and the common folder easily.
3. I do not want to use [Theme](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.theming) because I have different applications with different visual requirements and behaviors.

Any thoughts about this? Any good advices? Thanks in advance!

Comment: All you need is already in Boilerplate except Common auth Auth for all apps. Yii user authentication is application or module based, i think it can not be applied for all application by putting it in common.

Comment: You could add custom autoloader and register it to load before yii built in autoloader. Load any of your common component and if not found then let the yii autoloder deal with it in each application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found some way of how to do it.

First of all, my folders structure, looks similar as it:

```
common/
    css/
    images/
    js/
    extensions/
        bootstrap/
        auth/
    protected/
        /* Yii Default directory folder*/
Application1/
    css/
    images/
    js/
    protected/
        /* Yii Default directory folder*/
```

#### Config File Under Common Folder

```
return array(
    'import'=>array(
        'common.components.*',
        'common.models.*',
    ),
    'modules' => array(
        'auth',
    ),
    'components' => array(
        'authManager' => array(
            'behaviors' => array(
                'auth' => array(
                    'class' => 'common.modules.auth.components.AuthBehavior',
                    'admins'=>array('admin', 'foo', 'bar'), 
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'user' => array(
            'class' => 'common.modules.auth.components.AuthWebUser',
        ),
        'bootstrap'=>array(
            'class'=>'common2.extensions.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
        ),
    ),
);
```

### Login

The login is under 'common', so, to redirect to the login page, I just call the `SiteController.php` and I implented there the login process, giving for the user the ability to select the application that he wants to get in.

After the login, I redirect the user to the application address:

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->request->getBaseUrl(true) . "/../" .$App. "/" . "");
```

#### Config File Under Application Folder

under the application, the `index.php` file has the `alias` for the common directory, is the way that they can still 'talking'.

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('common', dirname(__FILE__) . $directory);
```

If you want to do something similar and are finding hard to understand, let me know, I will put here more information, if you need to.